# Using modules with almost similar functionality together on production site

Tags: 7, entities, installation

I have 2 modules with similar/alternative available and I have to use both. Those are [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api).

Now the situation is that there are few modules which require [References](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) and Search modules as a dependency. It is a need and I have to use it.

Can I use all these modules at the same time on a production site?

Is there any possibility of clash or site crash?

Comment: Did you try installing those modules on a test site, and see what happens? Apart that, I don't see any reason for installing the _Entity Reference_ and the _References_ modules at the same time, since their purpose is similar. Choose the one you need basing on your need, and other modules you need. If you need a module that depends from the _References_ module, you would not install the _Entity Reference_ module.

Comment: Yes, but not much. I guess it is risky because as clive said, it might cause problem some where sometime.

Comment: That is why changes are never done directly on a production site, but first tested on a test/staging site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's always a possibility that modules will be incompatible with other modules that do the same thing.

There's also the possibility that modules whose functionality is completely unrelated will be incompatible with one another. Such is the nature of a modularly extensible system.

The only way you'll know is if:

1. The documentation for one or more modules list their known issues with other modules, or
2. You thoroughly test the two modules while both installed on a single site